# Using docker-compose (formerly fig) to link a cron image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, docker, fig, docker-compose

I'm runing a simple rails app in docker using docker-compose (formerly fig) like this:

docker-compose.yml

```
db:
  image: postgres
  volumes:
    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

web:
  build: .
  command: bundle exec rails s -b 0.0.0.0
  volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
  ports:
    - "3011:3000"
  links:
    - db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM rails:onbuild
```

I need to run some periodical maintainance scripts, such as database backups, pinging sitemaps to search engines etc.

I'd prefer not to use cron on my host machine, since I prefer to keep the application portable and my idea is to use docker-compose to link an image such as https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/hamiltont/docker-cron/ using docker-compose.

The rails official image does not have ssh enabled so I cannot just have the cron container to ssh into the web container and run the scripts.

Does docker-compose have a way for a container to gain a shell into a linked container to execute some commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What actually would you like to do with your containers? If you need to access some objects from container's file system, you should just mount the volume to the ancillary container (consider `--volumes-from` option).

Any SSH interaction between containers is considered as a bad practice (at least since docker 1.3, when `docker exec` has been implemented). Running more than one process inside the container (e.g. smth but the `postgres` or `rails` in your case) will result in a large overhead: in order to have a `sshd` along with `rails` you'll have to deploy something like `supervisord`.

But if you really need to provide some kind of nonstandard interaction between the containers and you're sure that you really need it, I would suggest you to use one of the full-featured docker client libraries (like [`docker-py`](https://github.com/docker/docker-py)). It will allow you to launch `docker exec` in a programmable way.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information and for pointing me to docker-py. I just need to run some simple scheduled tasks like a weekly sitemap.xml ping to search engines, daily database dumps and upload of the dump to amazon S3, sending weekly email digest to registered users... Exactly the usual stuff I would set up cron jobs on a non docker environment.

Comment: @TopperH try to give a shot to the following design: mount `/var/run/docker.sock` to your `cron` container and install Docker inside it. You'll be able to execute docker commands from docker container. If Docker CLI is not enough, install the preferable docker client library (like `docker-py`) in `cron` too.

Comment: this sounds very interesting. I'll wait some more time before accepting your answer just in case there is a "docker-compose ready" solution around.

Comment: @TopperH, OK, please take your time :)

Comment: Doesn't this solution still have the same problem as the original - that it relies on the host's cron daemon?